# How do i get this 2*2 matrix by adding array in List

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        List<List<Integer>> list = new List<List<Integer>>();
        
        list.add({1,2,3});
        list.add({3,4,5});
        list.add({6,7,8});
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
    }
}
```

** I want the below matrix. And i want it by adding array to the List, but i amnot getting the desire output. Please let me know what i am missing.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

---

below code is working, and i have updated incase anyone needs....

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        
        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        list.add(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        list.add(Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
        list.add(Arrays.asList(7,8,9));
        
        System.out.println(list);
        
        System.out.println(list.get(0).get(0));
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write custom printing logic for that, manually iterate over `list` and its sub lists

Comment: Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. You seem to be under the impression that this here is a programming school where people teach you for free, and work with you through your assignments. Sorry, but that isnt the purpose of this place. Thus: please take some time to understand how this place works.

Comment: `List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();` is possible.

Comment: Possible doesn't mean "good". Sorry, @JoopEggen I find that a horrible advice to give to a java newbie.

Comment: @GhostCat you are right, I think a conceptual talk is in order; what is to achieve and how to ideally write it. But that `List<List<Integer>>` again _I_ find horrible.

Comment: Well, it depends. If you want to do a matrix with Lists, that is the way to go. If you want to do real world matrix work, then using some real world library is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot instantiate List because its interface you should create new list using one of list implementation e.g. Arraylist

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList>();
```

and adding to list

```
list.add(Arrays.asList(6,7,8));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.forEach(rowList -> {
  rowList.forEach(number -> System.out.print(number + " "));
  System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: @Boleslaw thanks, thats working. and it was simple and straight. Thank you. I have also added the working code, incase if anyone need.